# How to update a PDF file?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf, itext

I am required to replace a word with a new word, selected from a drop-down list by user, in a PDF document in ASP.NET. I am using iTextSharp , but the new PDF that is created is all distorted as I am not able to extract the formatting/styling info of the PDF while extracting. Also, IS There a way to read a pdf line-by-line? Please help..

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String s = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        Response.Write(s);
        ListFieldNames(s);
    }
    private void CreatePDF(string text)
    {
        string outFileName = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\Test_abc.pdf";
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.SetMargins(30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.BOLDITALIC);
        //Chunk ch = new Chunk(text,times);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(text,times);

        //para.SpacingAfter = 9f;
        para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //para.IndentationLeft = 100;
        doc.Add(para);


        //doc.Add(new Paragraph(text,times));
        doc.Close();
        Response.Redirect(@"z:\TEMP\PDF\Test_abc.pdf",false);




    }

    private void ListFieldNames(string s)
    {
        ArrayList arrCheck = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\abc.pdf";
            //string dest = @"z:\TEMP\PDF\Test_abc.pdf";

            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
            string pdfText = string.Empty;
            string extracttext = "";
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {

                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader((string)pdfTemplate);
                extracttext = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);
                extracttext = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extracttext)));
                pdfText = pdfText + extracttext;

                pdfText = pdfText.Replace("[xyz]", s);
                pdfReader.Close();
            }

            CreatePDF(pdfText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The iText parser classes are not (yet) meant for re-building PDFs but instead only for (plain) text and image extraction and for extraction of their locations and dimension. Furthermore please be aware that PDF is not intended as an editable format; *to replace a word with a new word,* therefore, is not a trivial endeaver but (for a generic solution) a Herculean task. That being said, if your task is limited to a special kind of PDFs, please post samples for inspection, maybe your documents are built in a way simplyfying the task considerably.

Comment: The word replacement is working fine. But, the new PDF created by this piece of code is devoid of all the styling info of the actual one. Is there any way to extract the styling info of the PDF as well along with the text...?

Comment: You do word replacement on the extracted plain text. Great if that's what you wanted. Otherwise completely irrelevant.

Comment: +1 on the comment by @mkl

Answer (score 2):

You are making one wrong assumption after the other.

1. You assume that the concept of "lines" exists in PDF. This is wrong. In Text State, different snippets of text are drawn on the page at absolute positions. For every "show text" operator, iText will return a `TextRenderInfo` object with the portion of text that was drawn and its coordinates. One line can consist of multiple text snippets. A text snippet may contain whitespace or may even be empty.
2. You assume that all text in a PDF keeps its natural reading order. This should be true for PDF/UA (UA stands for Universal Accessibility), but it's certainly not true for most PDFs you can find in the wild. That's why iText provides location-based text extraction (see p521 of [iText in Action, Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book)). As explained on p516, the text "Hello World" can be stored in the PDF as "ld", "Wor", "llo", "He". The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` will order all the text snippets, reconstructing words if necessary. For instance: it will concatenate "He" and "llo" to "Hello", because there's not sufficient space between the "He" snippet and the "llo" snippet. However, for reasons unknown (probably ignorance), you're using the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` which doesn't order the text based on its location.
3. You are completely ignoring all the Graphics State operators, as well as the Text State operators that define the font, etc...
4. You assume that PDF is a Word processing format. This is wrong on many levels, as is your code. Please read the intro of [chapter 6 of my book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

All these wrong assumptions almost make me want to vote down your question. At the risk of being voted down myself for this answer, I must tell you that you shouldn't try to "do the same". You're asking something that is very complex, and in many cases even impossible!

Comment: Actually the word replacement is working fine. But, the new PDF created by this piece of code is devoid of all the styling info of the actual one. Is there any way to extract the styling info of the PDF as well along with the text...?

Comment: As I explained in point 3 of my answer, you're ignoring all the Graphics State and Text State operators. Start reading ISO-32000-1 if you don't believe me when I say you're making too many wrong assumptions.